# What is different between American Oak and French Oak?

Tags: oak, flavor, ingredients

What other "nationalities" of Oak are used in brewing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know much about oak use in beermaking, but in winemaking, Frech oak is prized for giving a less "oaky" flavor while providing more tannins.  American oak contains a higher level of vanillins and imparts a stronger "oak" aroma.

Hungarian oak is also often used in winemaking.  I don't know anything about it.

I imagine these characteristics are taken into consideration for beermaking, though I might want to think that you'd prefer the American oak with more flavor/aroma and less tannins for beer, given that tannins aren't as welcome in beer as they are in wine, and the stronger flavor and aroma need to overcome the stronger flavor and aroma of a big, smoky beer as opposed to a delicate chardonnay or well-rounded syrah.